# How to deploy my Node.js Application with MongoDb on AWS ec2 or Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

***I got (Error code: HEALTH_CONSTRAINTS) when trying AWS CodeDeploy Service for ec2. And Denay Status error when using Elestic Beanstalk.***

```
In Elastic Beanstalk logs node.js log showing error MongoError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect
    at Pool.<anonymous> (/var/app/current/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:313:35)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Pool.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at Connection.<anonymous> (/var/app/current/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:271:12)
    at Connection.g (events.js:291:16)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/var/app/current/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:165:49)
    at Socket.g (events.js:291:16)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at emitErrorNT (net.js:1276:8)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
Server listening on port 8081.
```

Comment: It is difficult to resolve your problem, when you just post your error message. Post your steps of deployment and your app configuration

Comment: Thank you Lakshman. This error message because in my server.js file I am using localhost:27017 port to connect my Locally running Mongodb.

Comment: So are you deploying mongodb in the same instance ? Try posting your AWS codedeploy file, so that we can understand how mongodb and nodejs are deployed in EB.

Comment: When I try AWS code deploy service it shows (Error code: HEALTH_CONSTRAINTS).  I find don't stuck with Elestic Beanstalk or Code Deploy , Create ec2 server then using CLI (ssh -i...) upload code on ec2. then install npm package "forever" and execute script.

Answer (score 0):

I found alternative solution. I create an ec2 instance from AWS Marketplace (Mean powered by Bitnami). Then follow this tutorial https://scotch.io/tutorials/deploying-a-mean-app-to-amazon-ec2-part-1